# Where do I place my ad info on this wp theme sidebar.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is located in the sidebar.php file for predetermined adspace. I've tried putting the image URL and the link URL in separetely and by generated code, but I get an error every time. This is the code:

```
<div class="box"> <!-- Replace to your affiliate link -->
    <a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/images/ads125125.jpg" border="0px"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/images/ads125125.jpg" border="0px"></a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/images/ads125125.jpg" border="0px"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/images/ads125125.jpg" border="0px"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/images/ads125125.jpg" border="0px"></a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/images/ads125125.jpg" border="0px"></a>
</div>
```

I also do not see codes for placement in the sidebar such as left, center....or any other placement parameters. The errors vary. unexpected ">" line 6, unexpected "?" line 8, always an unexpected "something" line something. Always introd as syntax error. – Archangelm 2 hours ago Any help would be a blessing!!!

Comment: *Under no circumstances* reveal what error you are getting exactly! That would make it too easy. :P

Comment: The errors vary. unexpected ">" line 6, unexpected "?" line 8, always an unexpected "something" line something. Always introd as syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Check your stylesheet directory.
Place your images in the images folder and replace the image name like use your image name instead of ads125125.jpg.
To put your ads links change # with your ads links from